# React Admin, define custom saga for List

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

Is it possible to define a custom saga for the List component? I mean, when the List is mounted it dispatch the action `RA/CRUD_GET_LIST` that automatically (due to props passed down from parent components), fetches the data from the server. I want to define my own `RA/CRUD_GET_LIST` with different behaviour, is it possible?

List component:

```
<List
    {...this.sanitizeProps(this.props)}
    filter={{ userId: userId }}
    title="History"
    perPage={10}
>
    <DataGridComponent />
</List>
```

With `sanitizeProps` I filter the props that I need and pass down the others.

The resource I need to wait for is: `<Resource name="user" />`

I'm getting the `userId` from my custom reducer:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userId: state.userReducer.user.id
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your usecase first ?

Comment: I'm trying to pause the `RA/CRUD_GET_LIST` (http request) of a List until a specific `<Resource />` has completed the fetch. I've tried to add a custom saga that when `RA/CRUD_GET_LIST` is dispatched it's forced to wait for `FETCH_USER_SUCCESS`. `yield take(RA/CRUD_GET_LIST)`; but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you waiting for a resource to finish a fetch. I don't get it

Comment: I mean you are still describing a solution you tried, not your use case

Comment: Sorry, I need to wait for a `User` `Resource` to be fetched because in the `List` component I have a `filter` with the `id` of the `user`. On a page refresh the List would make the request with an empty filter (user fetch not completed), resulting in a `403`.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the List component code ?

Comment: Sure, edited the question

Comment: Can't see how you get the userId in your excerpt. Can you add that part too ?

Comment: Question updated; I'm getting the userId from a custom reducer. I call my own `fetchUser()` action when the main component is mounted. I need to wait for this action to complete before the `List` component dispatches its action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, it's not possible. However, you can achieve the result you want by wraping your List inside a connected component and only it render the `List` when you have a user_id. Otherwise, just return null or something indicating you're loading stuff.

```
const MyConnectedList = ({ userId, ...props }) =>
    userId
    ? (
       <List
           {...this.props}
           filter={{ userId }}
           title="History"
           perPage={10}
       >
           <DataGridComponent />
       </List>
    )
    : null
```